# How to reinstall Google download manager on rooted MOTO G X1032?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery, apk, downloading, download-manager

I'm on Android 5.0.2, rooted through Clockworkmod. I have Titanium Backup synced to my Dropbox and a Nandroid image.

I deleted the default download manager (stupidly on my Titanium Backup as well) to free up space, necessary despite having 100's of megs to spare - i think [this](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/how-fix-androids-insufficient-storage-available-error-message-3623467/) will fix that.

I've done a factory reset, but no luck. All my apps are wiped, including Titanium Backup and Nandroid (which i don't know how to restore to anyway).

Download Manager isn't visible in this [bundle](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/) of google APK's. Is it packaged with something else? Will i be able to run the APK when i do find it?

Edit: I've been advised to extract the download manager from a Custom ROM. How do i do this?

Comment: If you have an image backup, why don't you just restore it?

Comment: I don't know how to. If i go into fastboot mode and select recovery, all i get is "no command" and a android lying on it's back.

Comment: Try downloading gapps for your version of android and see if that adds it back. I forget what all is bundled into gapps.

Comment: How did you make the Nandroid backup?? Using recovery?? If yes, restore that again from the recovery

Comment: Ask someone here to post the apk: http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g

Comment: I've got a working MPT connection now. However, I don't think i can run the APK without the download manager. Is there a way of exracting it onto the phone from windows?